# Model is not a constructor? ts, mongoose, express

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose

I don't know why this has error "TypeError: PartyModel is not a constructor" 
what can I do for it? 
I already do something for it, but it has other error too 
I did const { ... } = require("./model/...) but it has "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')"

app.ts

```js
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";

const cors = require("cors")
import mongoose from "mongoose"
const configModel = require("./model/ConfigSchema")
const PartyModel = require("./model/PartySchema")

const app = express()

...

app.post('/createParty', cors(), async function (req: CustomRequest<partyModelInterface>, res: Response) {
    const input = req.body

    const today = new Date()

    await reloadConfig()

    const party = new PartyModel({
        id: partyNumber,
        game: input.game,
        master: input.master,
        description: input.description,
        players: input.players,
        time: today
    })

    partyNumber++

    saveToDb(party)

    res.send("파티가 생성되었습니다")
})
```

PartySchema.ts

````js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const partySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    game: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    master: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    players: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    time: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
}, {
    versionKey: false,
    collection: 'parties'
})

module.exports =  mongoose.model('Party', partySchema)```
````

Comment: Add `console.log(PartyModel)` before using it to see what it actually is. Code looks okay as-is, but I suspect a circular dependency (in which case `PartyModel` will be `undefined`).

Comment: unfortunately it's not undefined, it returns some object

Comment: Please add that information to your question (including the object).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Model.create()` method to create a db model like this:

```
const party = await PartyModel.create({
        id: partyNumber,
        game: input.game,
        master: input.master,
        description: input.description,
        players: input.players,
        time: today
    });
```

Comment: [`Model.create()` is a shortcut for `new Model().save()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.create). If `new Model()` doesn't work, why do you think `Model.create()` will?